# Can i get pevious value form (change)="$event"?

Tags: angular

I wonder if I can get information about previous value from angular event. I try to avoid store previous value in variable. I tried to find appropriate property in $event object but I didnt find anything.

In my bigger project I get array from http-service.

[stackblitz with this problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttohej?embed=1&file=src/app/home/home.component.ts&view=preview)

Comment: What's the problem with storing the previous value?

Comment: I just wonder if exist build-in solution. I don't want to re-inventing the wheel ;)

Comment: [ReplaySubject](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you'll have to change things around.

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" (ngModelChange)="actions(selectedValue, $event); selectedValue = $event" [ngModel]="selectedValue">
```

...

```
  actions(previousValue, newValue) {
    this.valueFromAction = newValue; // value chose by user
    // selectedValue equals valueFromAction now
    // how can i got previous value here?
    this.previousValue = `The previous value was ${previousValue}`;
  }
```

Working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tuinvh?file=src%2Findex.html

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code ... I'm not sure exactly how you have this.

If you are referring to `@Input()` properties, then you can use the passed in `SimpleChanges`:

```
export class CriteriaComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() displayDetail: boolean;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes['displayDetail'].previousValue);
    console.log(changes['displayDetail'].currentValue);
  }
}
```

If you are using reactive forms, then there are two values: the *original* value and the *current value*.

If you just want the select element to hold the prior value, there is no built-in way for it to do that. It only has one `value`.

For a larger project, you may want to consider using NgRx. It keeps track of the state of your application.

Comment: Thanks :) good idea, but in my bigger project I get array from http-service. I forgot to add this :/ Simple example is in aboved link